# facebook page plugin not working in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1680466125563156',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };



  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Hireatent" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="300" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">

    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/Hireatent">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Hireatent">Hire-a-Tent</a>   </blockquote>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have added the above-mentioned code in my webpage but when I open the index.html in my local machine I am not getting the desired output (fb page timeline is not showing up instead I just get a link to my FB page (see attached image)

[image]

Is this because I am opening this in my local machine or am I missing something  here?  TIA

Comment: Yes, assuming you're opening the file over `file:///` protocol, the SDK will not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

To This:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```